# Azure Functions - Initialization Logic

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I am trying to understand Azure functions with HTTP Trigger -

1. Where should I be putting the initialization code which I intend to run only once and not on every HTTP Call. Like, connecting to Keyvault, Loading master data from database etc.
2. Is there a way multiple functions can share memory. I might want to use same Keyvault and database in multiple azure functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function invocations are meant to be independent from each other, so there is no way to guarantee that some code is executed only once. If your function comes under heavy load, it might even be distributed to multiple machines and they all operate independent.

However, what you can do is declare static variables in you function and they will often retain their value between invocations. Often, no guarantees!

Secondly, there is no way you can share memory between invocations. To share state, you should fall back on other storage solutions like a Redis Cache for example

Comment: Should I be creating a Static Constructor in the Function class to initialize all static variables? Is there any other recommended pattern for maintainability and avoid code duplication.

Comment: A static constructor is one option. Other options are to just initialize variables inline e.g. private List<T> _list = new List<T>() or to use a Singleton implementation

Now, if your one time setup is so complex that this is not sufficient, I wonder, are Functions the right solution for your problem?